# Is the Map Api Key and Google Places Api the same?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, google-places-api

I hope I don't get a down vote, English is not my first language that is why I get confused by api documentations.  I am confused if I need to generate different api keys for "Google Maps Android API" and "Google Places API for Android"

I am asking because I am sucessfully rendering maps from my android app using google maps android api but when I try the using the code of the official google android places api example (PLACE PICKER) it is failing without throwing any errors.  It renders the activity properly but when I click the find places button it just returns me to my previous activity with no error.  I am guessing it might be an api key issue that is why I am asking if I need two different api keys for this?

Comment: Post logcat with the error

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#add_the_api_key_to_your_application Read the last section along with the note in blue square. According to this https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/start#api-key both services use the same API key specified in `com.google.android.geo.API_KEY` meta-data.

Comment: @grewywolf82 there is no error it loads with no errors but when you click "pick place" it shows the place finder activity where the map should also be, and shortly after that returns you to the main activity.  Is there a way or message where it would say that its a api key issue? will it warn me in some way if its an apk issue?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, each service (Google Maps V2 API and Google Places API) have and will generate a different API Key.
But you can't use/declare both keys in your manifest in the same time. When you are using Google Maps and Google Places just use the Google Places API key only (com.google.android.geo.API_KEY), and it will work for both.

Comment: I am using both but it's working fine See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42106186/3496570

Answer (score 1):

Look at this link at android developers
https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/signup#release-cert

> You need an Android API key, not a browser key. You can use the same API key for your Google Maps Android API v2 apps and your Google Places API for Android apps.