# Difference between com.google.android.geo.api_key and com.google.android.maps.v2.api_key?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-manifest

I would like to know what is difference between `com.google.android.geo.API_KEY` & `com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY` meta tags. They are both used for setting Google Maps API Key. But cannot seem to find the difference and which is preferable to use ?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36112984/is-the-map-api-key-and-google-places-api-the-same

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup):

> **Note:** As shown above, com.google.android.geo.API_KEY is the
>   recommended metadata name for the API key. A key with this name can be
>   used to authenticate to multiple Google Maps-based APIs on the Android
>   platform, including the Google Maps Android API. For backwards
>   compatibility, the API also supports the name
>   com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY. This legacy name allows
>   authentication to the Android Maps API v2 only. An application can
>   specify only one of the API key metadata names. If both are specified,
>   the API throws an exception.

Comment: What this line supposed to mean?
`This legacy name allows authentication to the Android Maps API v2 only.`